# Is my Android phone camera hacked?

Tags: android, permissions

I suddenly see a strange thing when developing my Flutter application. My application that I'm developing is not asking for permissions, it does not need any permissions. But when I debug the app in my own physical Android phone device, I see that logs below which it looks like the camera is open and recording. I have closed my app and it's showing the logs again, and I checked if the camera is open in the recent apps, but it's closed. It's so strange. I did some research but I can't find anything.

```
I/CameraManagerGlobal(31346): Camera 2 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_OPEN for client com.samsung.android.smartface API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal(31346): Camera 2 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_ACTIVE for client com.samsung.android.smartface API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal(31346): Camera 2 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_IDLE for client com.samsung.android.smartface API Level 2
I/CameraManagerGlobal(31346): Camera 2 facing CAMERA_FACING_FRONT state now CAMERA_STATE_CLOSED for client com.samsung.android.smartface API Level 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not *hacked*. It's just **bloated** by Samsung software.

What you see is a log of `com.samsung.android.smartface` *leaking* (if I can say that) into your application log.

This because `logcat` monitors logs globally and doesn't natively filter for your application only.

It is a Samsung application named "SmartFace".

What it does is to continuously activate front camera to scan for the user's face and detect eyes open in order to keep the screen always-on.

([source](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2334442))

> keep the screen on if you look at the phone: smart face

It is also a known bloatware

**Conclusion**

Another good reason to debloat devices